# Deleting published app from developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an app, it failed somehow (.apk tested before publishing it was fine, I don't know how it failed in store) Anyway I unpublished and ready to upload another one.

As you know you need the original keystore for installing another version, I lost the key, I didn't know it was important. So I created another app.

As I read you cannot delete published apps, but it was all old answers. Is there a way to delete published (now unpublished of course) app from developer console? It is kinda annoying to see a useless app there. Like contact Google or somehow?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted them about the same thing and they said an app cannot be deleted once it is published (even it if is un-published). :(

Comment: Oh man, that is very annoying. I wonder why they don't allow. At least developer should delete after a while. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It makes sense that you cannot delete them but we should at least be able to HIDE them.